# Can't add another partition on a HP-Mini 110 netbook

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, partitioning, ubuntu-netbook

I would like to ask about partitioning a Netbook HP-Mini 110 with Windows 7 Starter. I want to install a dual boot in it  with Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is that it already has 4 partitions and it doesn't allow any more partitions to added. I can't delete the other partitions to make new ones because it is the recovery and the system fix tool of Windows 7. Is there still a way to create a separate partition for Ubuntu?

Also my AP Hotspot doesn't work on myHP Mini in Ubuntu 14.04. It says in 14.04, AP Hotspot is not working so a downgrade of the app is needed. On my other laptop with the same distro it's working well.

What do you think might be the problem?

Comment: It would be ideal if you limit one question per post. If you have multiple issues start a new question for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have more than 4 primary partitions if you use MBR partition scheme(3 primary + 1 extended (which can have several 'child' partitions)). Since you say you already have 4 partitions, one of it must be extended (and other 3 will be primary) Suppose if you have C, D, E and F drives, and for eg: F: is your extended partition you can install Ubuntu on this partition (back up your data before doing this!). Boot from a Ubuntu live USB and select this drive to install Ubuntu. If you want to install Ubuntu with different partitions i.e with separate `/boot`, `home` `/` etc. you will need to partition the existing 'extended' partitions in Windows.

If you can provide a picture on how your partitions look in windows it would be helpful for everyone to give more detailed/specific suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to convert one or more of your existing primary partitions from primary to logical form non-destructively using my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) (`fixparts`, part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu) or with some third-party Windows tools (I have no specific programs to recommend, aside from the Windows version of FixParts, but I hear that some Windows tools can do this). ***DO NOT*** attempt to add partitions using the standard Windows tools; they'll convert the disk to the Windows-proprietary [Logical Disk Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) format.

Note that you *must not* convert any bootable partition to logical form. Also, you may need to slightly shrink a partition to convert the one *after* it, since you need a small gap before each logical partition.

Another option is to create an external recovery disc and delete the partition that handles the same task.